# Super User Question of the Week #29

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 29 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: HA. loved the comment in my inbox ;)

Comment: so tempted to close as dupe ;)

Comment: I just love the related questions section on the right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Why is my dual-core CPU recognized as a quad-core one?](https://superuser.com/questions/329918/why-is-my-dual-core-cpu-recognized-as-a-quad-core-one)

Interesting discussion about how hyperthreaded CPUs are recognized as having twice as many cores as they actually do.

Comment: Good choice - I'd write this one

Comment: Related question: [What are threads, and what do they do in the processor?](http://superuser.com/questions/329904/what-are-threads-and-what-do-they-do-in-the-processor)

Comment: This tied with "why does an 8 GB and 16 GB USB drive have the same physical size buy a different amount of storage", but this one is much easier for us to write about.

Answer (score 7):

## [Why does an 8 GB and 16 GB USB drive have the same physical size but a different amount of storage?](https://superuser.com/questions/328029/why-does-an-8-gb-and-16-gb-usb-drive-have-the-same-physical-size-but-a-different)

This question has turned up some interesting stuff about how memory chips are manufactured. Might make for a good blog post.

Comment: Very interesting. I would like to see something this explained in more detail. It would be super awesome to get someone to somehow have microscopic images of the actual memory chips similar to this: http://www.sciencystuff.com/?p=24

Comment: @KronoS haha, those are pretty awesome. But I'm not sure if we can get our hands on an electron microscope for blog posts?

Comment: @DMA57361 agreed, that might be a bit out of our price range.

Answer (score 3):

## [How to find the process(es) which are hogging the machine](https://superuser.com/questions/326300/how-to-find-the-processes-which-are-hogging-the-machine)

I thought it was a really cool question, and one that would be handy to know. If I were to write about it, I would be doing testing on Windows.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, please state why, if possible.